# Accesing input element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, perl, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm not experienced with Javascript so any help would be very appriciated. For you guys this should be very easy. I posted a lot of code but my problem is just to copy 3 input fields values into a string/variable and use it for geocoding.

I have this inputs in a table:

```
<table width="580px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="290"><label for="street">Street:</label></td>
<td width="278"><INPUT type="text" name="obj_object_description_street" id="obj_object_description_street" class="inputField" autocomplete="off" /></td>
<td width="12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="290"><label for="streetno">House number:</label></td>
<td width="290"><INPUT type="text" name="obj_object_description_streetno" id="obj_object_description_streetno" class="inputField" autocomplete="off" /></td>
<td width="12">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="290"><label for="zipcode">Post number:* </label></td>
<td width="290"><INPUT type="text" name="obj_object_description_zipcode" id="obj_object_description_zipcode" class="inputField" autocomplete="off" /><INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="sys_area_node_id" /></td>
<td width="12"><img src="/img/info.gif" alt="info" width="12" height="11" border="0" onclick="show_info(this,8);" onmouseover="make_pointer();" onmouseout="del_pointer();" /></td>
</tr>
```

And this code to display a google map with dragable pin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var geox='<%obj_object_description_geox%>';  //Location from DB
 var geoy='<%obj_object_description_geoy%>';  //Location from DB
 var sgeox='<%sys_area_geox%>';
 var sgeoy='<%sys_area_geoy%>';
 var telefon = "<%adv_advertiser_phone%>";
 var slika = "<%main_media_web_url%>";
 var povrsina = "<%area%>";
 var cijena = "<%price_str%>";
 var naslov = '<%headline%>';
 var posta = "<%obj_object_description_zipcode%>";
 var ulica = "<%obj_object_description_street%>";
 var broj =  "<%obj_object_description_streetno%>"; 
 var address = "";


function initialize_map(){
  if(geox != 0 && geoy != 0) //we have gps
  { 
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geox, geoy);  
    show_map(myLatlng);
  }
  else if(sgeox!=0 && sgeoy !=0)
  {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(sgeox, sgeoy);
     show_map(myLatlng);
  }
  else //no? we do the old good geocoding
  {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': '<%bc_sys_area_name%>, <%bc_sys_area_name_2%>'}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

           show_map(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
     }
    });


  } 
}



</script>
```

My problem is :

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': '<%bc_sys_area_name%>, <%bc_sys_area_name_2%>'}, function(results, status)
```

I dont want to geocode <%bc_sys_area_name%>, <%bc_sys_area_name_2%> from the database. I want to geocode with a combined data of inputs(Street + House number + Post number).
Street has name & id obj_object_description_street
House has name & id obj_object_description_streetno
Post number has name & id obj_object_description_zipcode.

I have made a function that put's together all this 3 values:
UPDATED:
My problem is that i use this function for copying 3 inputs in a input with id="geocomplete" and I need this function to copy this values onload(when the page opens/refreshes) to an input  not just when i type(keyup event).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$('#obj_object_description_street, #obj_object_description_streetno, #obj_object_description_zipcode').bind('keypress blur', function() {

    $('#geocomplete').val($('#obj_object_description_street').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#obj_object_description_streetno').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#obj_object_description_zipcode').val() );

});


    </script>
```

But I dont know how to put all this 3 data into a string/variable and put it in

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': 'HERE IT SHOULD BE'}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer based on your feedback. I would suggest to use [jquery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. I've created an example here, but you probably need to tweak a little bit. Basically, I've created two functions and I call them in different times, when page loads and when a keypress event happens.

```
 $(function() {
   $('#obj_object_description_street, #obj_object_description_streetno, #obj_object_description_zipcode').bind('keypress blur', function() {
     $('#geocomplete').val(geoComplete());
     updateGeoCoder(); //do this if you want to make a geocode call everytime you have this event 
   });

   function geoComplete() {
    return $('#obj_object_description_street').val()   + ' ' +
           $('#obj_object_description_streetno').val() + ' ' +
            $('#obj_object_description_zipcode').val() ;
   }

   function updateGeoCoder() {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var geoCompleteVal = $('#geocomplete').val();
     geocoder.geocode( {'address': geoCompleteVal}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         show_map(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '+ status);
       }
     });
   }

   //this is to run as soon as the page loads/refresh
   $('#geocomplete').val(geoComplete());
   updateGeoCoder();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for yout help, I really appriciate it!:)
In fact I have to get this values updated dynamicly based  on user input value changing(street, zipcode, street number).

 Also my problem is that i use function for copying 3 inputs in a input with id="geocomplete" and i would wand this function to copy this values onload(when the page opens/refreshes) not just when i tyle(keyup event). I updated my question so you can understand it better. Thank you very much once more!